# Variable-size vectors as input for keras?

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I'm trying to set up a simple NN using Keras with Theano backend, to categorise some data. The features of the data are either `float` or `vector<float>` (inherited from the C++ script used to generate them).

Now, if the vectors all had a fixed length from data point to data point, I'd be happy enough to unpack them and treat each element as a single feature in the input layer to my NN; unfortunately, this is not the case.

Is there anything I can do to make my keras setup accept such variable-size input? I'm currently manipulating the data with `pandas`, and can either have those vectors as pythonic lists, or use a `MultiIndex` (subentries).

Any help welcome!

Comment: I'm realising this is similar to asking whether `numpy` handles jagged arrays, which it doesn't...

Comment: There are 2 ways to deal with a vector of data: Either consider them independent features or a sequence of values and process them with a recurrent or convolution layer.

Comment: Hi @PedroMarques, I'd started considering retaining only a subset of those vectors and turning them into independent features as a pre-processing step, but I take it your suggestions would allow me to keep the full vectors? Could you expand a bit? Thanks!

Comment: Simplest approach possible is to do what you had considered originally. Determine the max size of the vector<float> and create N features where N is the max size. Then depending on the application you may want to do something different. e.g. if the sequence of values is relevant.